# alternative for 'in practice' or 'in reality'

Tags: expressions

I am looking for a more punchy way to say 'in practice,'  ie what happens in the 'real world'.  I've looked at In reality, In practice, In the real world. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [De facto](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/de-facto?s=t)

> 1.
>   in fact; in reality:
>
> E.g. Although the school was said to be open to all qualified students, it still practiced de facto segregation.

Antonym: [De jure](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/de-jure)

Answer (score -1):

'Pragmatically speaking' would be a good alternative

Comment: But *why* is it good? We are looking for answers that explain their reasoning, ideally with sources.